# WEB3.SHA3 JSON CURL

Tags: json-rpc, sha3, keccak

I am trying to convert the string function name Double(int256) to hash using the Keccak-256 SHA3 algorithm using web3sha3 for curl.

In geth I use the command as such `web3.sha3('double(int256)')` and it works nicely.

However trying this using a curl command as such doesn't work.

```
curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"web3_sha3","params":["double(int256]","id":64}'
```

Do I have to convert the function name into some other format first  before using curl to make it work?

Answer (score 2):

and moments later I figure it out..

You have to convert the string to hexadecimal and use that as the input for the params